# Error while using Webpack in reactApp creation- configuration.output.path: The provided value "./" is not an absolute path!"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, windows-10

I was following online tutorial to create first app in ReactJS. After doing manual package installations using npm in node. After setup completion I am facing issue while trying to run npm start, getting error like : "Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.  - configuration.output.path: The provided value "./" is not an absolute path!".

Please let me know where something went wrong.

Do find the snapshot in attachment.[Webpack error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fz7VB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`./` is not a **absolute** path, it's a **relative** path. Absolute paths are paths from the root folder on your filesystem - a *nix example would be `/var/www/something/`. Relative paths are relative from the current working directory - if you were in `/var/www/`, `./something/` would be equivalent to the example absolute path. if you want the current directory, you can use `__dirname`, which is an absolute path.

edit: I see you're on Windows 10 (from the tag), an absolute path on Windows would look like `C:/Users/something/...`

Comment: I am using windows 10 and absolute path given is
 path: 'C:\Users\yyy\Desktop\WebApps\reactApp'
somehow it is still showing error.

Comment: Hi,Issue got resolved when path used with __dirname  + '/path'

Comment: Hi,Issue got resolved when path used as below:

   output: {
      path: __dirname,
      filename: 'index.js',
   }.
Thanks for the help!!